# Why does floor_date prevent geom_rect() to draw?

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate

I'd like to know why these two code snippets
won't produce the same results. Why are these two charts different ?

```
library("ggplot2")
library("lubridate")

# This will draw a line only
a <- data.frame(
    day=c(floor_date(ymd_hms("2021/12/20 10:00:00"), unit="days"),
          floor_date(ymd_hms("2021/12/21 11:11:11"), unit="days")),
    start=c(10,20),
    end=c(50,60))
ggplot(a) + geom_rect(aes(xmin=day,xmax=day+1,ymin=start, ymax=end)) + geom_line(aes(x=day,y=start))

# This will draw a line *and* a rectangle
a <- data.frame(
    day=c(ymd("2021/12/20"),
          ymd("2021/12/21")),
    start=c(10,20),
    end=c(50,60))
ggplot(a) + geom_rect(aes(xmin=day,xmax=day+1,ymin=start, ymax=end)) + geom_line(aes(x=day,y=start))
```

Edit: replaced `day+0.5` with `day+1` to avoid misleading to a rounding issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class of day is POSIXct for the first and Date for the second example. The `+` operator does things differently:

```r
library("lubridate")
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

floor_date(ymd_hms("2021/12/20 10:00:00"), unit="days") + 0.5
#> [1] "2021-12-20 00:00:00 UTC"
ymd("2021/12/21") + 0.5
#> [1] "2021-12-21"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The first example will lead into bars of width 0.

Comment: When changing the 0.5 into 1 in the given code, it still gives the issue described (I tested)

Comment: +1 on an object of class POSIXct will increase the time by one second, but the width of your x tick is 1 day, so still almost 0

Comment: Yep, I figured it out, thinking about your answer while walking :-) You're definitely right (I tested, adding 3600*24 to `day` makes it work).